# Camunda Spin : No matching data format detected

Tags: javascript, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am getting the error "The process could not be started. : SPIN-01004 No matching data format detected" 
while trying to start my process.
The response if the service task is a JSON String. "{"\key\":"\value\"}"
I have set the output parameter in bpmn  as shown below:

```
        <camunda:outputParameter name="Result">
          <camunda:script scriptFormat="Javascript">S(response).prop('key1').value();</camunda:script>
        </camunda:outputParameter>
```

And I am taking the ouptut value of result variable as the input of the next service task uri.
Could you please help.

Comment: What happens when you write `S(response, 'application/json')...`?

Comment: @thorben ..It did not change anything.
"The process could not be started. : 
SPIN-01004 No matching data format detected"